# How to instantiate an anonymous es6 class within itself

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs

Say I was parsing a tree where a Node could instantiate another Node as a child. This is pretty easy when the class is named:

```
class Node {
    parseLeaves( leaves ) {
        _.each( 
            leaves,
            ( leaf ) => {
                this.leaves.push( new Node( leaf ) );
            }
        );
    }
}
```

But what if the class was exported without being named first? How could the class be determined? i.e.

```
export default class {
    parseLeaves( leaves ) {
        _.each( 
            leaves,
            ( leaf ) => {
                this.leaves.push( new ???( leaf ) ); 
            }
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to put `exports.default` in place of `???`

Comment: @AdnanUmer that's it! If you want to submit as an answer I'll select it

Comment: I described a slightly better but still poor idea below. Please, before putting this in your code, take a look =)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I look deeper into JS generated by ES6 compilers, `export default` value is stored as `exports.default`.

So, you can still refer that unnamed class using `exports.default`

```
export default class {
    parseLeaves( leaves ) {
        _.each( 
            leaves,
            ( leaf ) => {
                this.leaves.push( new exports.default( leaf ) ); 
            }
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: This takes advantage of the fact that ES6 compilers compile these down to CommonJS format. This wouldn't work with native ES6.

Comment: For future reference, while this is the "correct" answer the criticisms @slezica raises are valid.

Comment: Please don't mix module systems.

Answer (score 10):

It's possible to do what you ask, but **I do not recommend it**.

All objects in javascript have a `constructor` property, that points to their class. By "objects", I mean this is true of everything except `null` and `undefined`.

```
export default class {
  createAnotherInstance() {
    return new this.constructor()
  }
}
```

This is not a good idea, for at least two important reasons:

1. Unnamed classes make debugging harder. Stack traces that go through the class will lack a helpful name. People inspecting your objects will not know what they're dealing with. If all your classes follow this pattern, a variable that holds an unexpected type will be *very hard* to detect.
2. Subclasses that invoke `createAnotherInstance` will return subclass instances (their own `constructor`), when you may have wanted the base class. Even if you desire this, the approach makes it look like an accident. In three days time you'll forget, and it may come back to bite you.

I would name the class, if I were you. Names are good. Unnamed things are ambiguous, and only to be used in contexts where there is no other possible interpretation, for either the computer or the programmer.

```
export default class Node { ... }
```

Comment: Points taken. Although this would be no worse than working in ES5 code in those regards.